# Как правильно обратиться к функции в Пролог, чтобы она вернула ответ?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Как правильно обратиться к этой функции `купил_путёвку(x,y)`, чтобы она вернула ответ, например отвела точно на такой вопрос, где Иван или Петя купили путёвку, я пытаюсь обратится следующем образом `купил_путёвку(X,Y)`, но мне выдаёт сообщение `false`, хотя должен выдать ответ, например , `оптисофт` или `авиатор`.

```
деньги('Ivan',есть).%есть деньги
деньги('Petya',есть).%есть деньги
паспорт('Ivan',есть).%у Ивана есть паспорт
паспорт('Petya',есть).%у Пети есть паспорт
ближе(авиатор,оптисофт).%Оптисофт ближе, чем авиатор

купил_путёвку(x,y):-ближе(x,y),деньги(x,y),паспорт(x,y).
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, попытался отредактировать формулировку вопроса, чтобы он был более понятнее.

Comment: Убрал всё лишнее.

Comment: да точно, это важно, поменял код на более рабочий и добавил конкретную ошибку и код выделил тегами

Comment: попробуй во всех местах заменить `x`, `y` на `X`, `Y`

Comment: Заменил, ответ вот такой купил_путёвку(X,Y)     false

Comment: почему в одном случае используется просто `авиатор`, а в другом с кавычками `'авиатор'`?

Comment: в первом случае, человек выбирает в какую фирму пойдёт в зависимости какая ближе, во втором случае показывается как зовут продовца который работает в конкретной фирме

Comment: предикат принимает два параметра: `X` и `Y`, сначала они специфицируются со значениями персонала, например `'авиатор',алина`, далее уже эти значения подставляются в `ближе2` и так как не соответствуют ни одному факту - получается `false`.

Comment: То есть проблема не в правильном обращении к функции, а в том, что сама функция - неправильная

Comment: а как можно исправить запрос и функцию? например если я так функцию вызываю ,то получается тоже неправильный запрос? купил_путёвку(X,Y),персонал('авиатор',алина)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116319/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Comment: У меня если честно основная проблема я не понимаю как вообще можно отправить запрос к такой структуре, купил путёвку как правильно вызвать.   купил_путёвку(x,y):-ближе(x,y),деньги(x,y),паспорт(x,y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как правильно обратиться к этой функции купил_путёвку(x,y), чтобы она вернула ответ, например отвела точно на такой вопрос, где Иван или Петя купили путёвку...

Решение:

```
 имеет(иван, деньги).
    имеет(иван, паспорт).
    
    имеет(петя, деньги).
    имеет(петя, паспорт).
    
    ближе(авиатор, оптисофт).% Оптисофт ближе, чем авиатор
    
    купил_путёвку(Person, TourOp):-
         ближе(_, TourOp),
         имеет(Person, деньги),
         имеет(Person, паспорт).
        
        
        Запрос:
        ?- купил_путёвку(Person, TourOp).
    
        Person = иван,
        TourOp = оптисофт
Next:       
        Person = петя,
        TourOp = оптисофт
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, а вы какой пролог используете? у меня просто ошибку выдаёт когда запрашиваю к вашей программе так  купил_путёвку(иван, авиатор).                                                                       
   Singleton variables: [X]

Comment: поменял переменную x на маленькую, но мне при запросе выдаёт следующее купил_путёвку(иван,авиатор)   - false . Если есть возможность можете пожалуйста подсказать, как получить конкрентый ответ?

Comment: я использую компилятор https://swish.swi-prolog.org

Comment: Я в основном использую SWI. "Маленьких" переменных в Прологе нет:  x - это атом.

Comment: спасибо)) помогли разобраться